how to repair NTFS SSD after ubuntu24 desktop crash
Background
Ubuntu 24.04 crashed - unable to automount SSD after force restart
I have tried sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd  but it not work.
Disk check and repair in Windows11 can solve the problem, maybe windows use chkdsk command. but how repair in ubuntu.
update:
following :

1 Fix corrupt NTFS partition without Windows

2 I'm running fsck and getting "ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block"


I tried his command and get below info:
sudo e2fsck -c /dev/sdd
[sudo] password for user-name: 
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdd

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdd

And I also tried sudo fsck -f /dev/sdd1 and reboot, it not work.
BTW:
I don't have enough prestige to comment. So I have to open a new asking.

There is no chkdsk command in GNU/Linux or Unix; there is a command of that name in Microsoft DOS & Microsoft Windows, but that's a different OS

chkdsk software is not compatible with Ubuntu.
It cannot be run on an Ubuntu system.
